# Responsive jsCarousel V2.0

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

I have implement jsCarousel v2.0 
Demo Link http://www.egrappler.com/contents/jscarouselv2/demo/jscarousel-2.0.0.htm

My whole site is Responsive but when jsCarousel v2.0 runs it works when i open site on Portrait Mode or Landscape Mode

But when i move from Portrait Mode to Landscape Mode it does'nt detect correct mode

```
if ( jQuery(window).width() > 1200 ){
 var a=5;
}
else if ( jQuery(window).width() >= 949 ){
var a=5;}
else if ( jQuery(window).width() >= 768 ){
var a=3;}
else if ( jQuery(window).width() >= 600 ){
var a=2;}
else if ( jQuery(window).width() >= 480 ){
var a=2;}
else if ( jQuery(window).width() >= 320 ){
var a=1;}

$.fn.extend({
jsCarousel: function(options) {
var settings = $.extend({
scrollspeed: 500,
delay: 5000,
itemstodisplay: a,
autoscroll: false,
onthumbnailclick: null
}, options);
```

Please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You should add something like this code around, which triggers when the window size changes.

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () { 

});
```

But your code is a plugin code?